# Too much reduced page content in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm using the follwoing methods to reduce page content in WebView:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

also I tried this, it gave the same result:

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
```

The problem:
it works in all AVD versions, but everywhere it reduces the page content too much (very small content and free spaces on sides). See screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/vhv5zvpk1/

And here is WebView without reducing methods: http://postimg.org/image/6ue99x6bd/

There is just a pure HTML with one div:

```
<body bgcolor="#009f9e"><center><div align="center" class="txt" style="width:350px;">
<img src="cat.jpg" hspace="10" vspace="10" border="0" class="picbord"><br>
<strong>Title text</strong><br>
Description text is here<br>
<a href="link.php" class="txt2"><img src="button.png" width="152" height="29" hspace="10" vspace="10" border="0" /></a>
</div></center>
</body>
```

Without reducing it doesn't fit the AVD screen, so the original page content is quite large. Could anyone help please?

Comment: You should at least post two screenshots as how would we know the influence of statements?

Comment: You are right, thanks. 2nd screenshot added to the post

Comment: Well, nobody knows... I got correct reducing by javascript in html and voila! F*ck Android.